# Flutter - Getting empty list of snapshot.docs when printing one of collection in firestore database

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I am just running this simple code in initstate :

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('messages').snapshots().listen((xxx) {
      print("hhhh${xxx.docs}");
    });
```

but the result is always empty list. I have tried to print another collection, like "users" and the list is not empty (the result is like in firebase database. but whenever I call "messages" it always gettiong empty list. is there a way to solve this ?
Here is a pict of the firebase database :
[image]

second pict :

[image]

Comment: The document ID in `messages` shows in *italics*, which means that there is actually no document with that ID and the console only show it because there are subcollections under it. If your screenshot you can also see a message to that effect in the bottom right panel. --- Since there is no document, it won't be returned by read operations. The solution is to ensure a document exists with that ID, even if that document contains no actual data.